# Arduino Pro Micro not recognised by computer or showing up in ports

Tags: arduino-micro

Around 4 days ago my Arduino Pro Micro arrived. I've been messing around with it, using it to run keyboard commands on a computer. Just recently, whenever I plug it in to the computer it isn't detected by ports or anything. The green light is still on, and the left red light (looking at it from the side of the micro USB input) still works as well, however the right red light no longer works. Can someone tell me what's happening? Have I broken it all ready?

Comment: What was the last sketch you uploaded to it?

Answer (score 2):

The `arduino pro micro` is notoriously difficult to program. I am sure you have figured this out when first installing the drivers but on power up, the micro runs a `bootloader` for `<750ms`  so for me at least, it was extremely difficult to install drivers.

However, if you look at [this guide by sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pro-micro--fio-v3-hookup-guide/troubleshooting-and-faq#ts-reset), you will see that resetting the board in quick succession will load a longer `8 sec` bootloader, which gives your more time to program it. Obviously, this is not normally something you need to worry about as the `Arduino IDE` automatically resets the board sending it into the bootloader when you upload a sketch to it.

Back to your problem, if it is not popping up as a device when you plug it in to your computer, go into `control panel > system > hardware > device manager` and look to see if you can find it there. If it still doesn't show up, do what I said above and reset it twice and hopefully you will see the bootloader appear where you can reinstall the drivers for it. You can find the appropriate drivers in the same location where you installed the `IDE` originally.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to tack onto a 4yr old thread, but hoping this helps others, as it would have me.

Unbeknownst to me,some USB micro cables are power-only and don't have the data lines. I had one of these in my rotation of cables, and while the LEDs lit up nicely, the USB does not appear. I was sure it was not a cable prob as I thought I'd tried multiples. I was unaware I had one of these power only USB cables about - marked with the USB Trident just like the others.

So if you have the 'dead USB' problem with your Pro Micro, do make the effort to be absolutely sure of your cable situation.

I read the debugging posts across the web far and wide, but I yada-yada'd the cable check, as I never saw anyone point out the cable might be undamaged, but just a null-data variant.  My bad obvs - but just FYI for others like me.